# Tomboy synchronization with Ubuntu One fails

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, tomboy

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 desktop (amd64).  When I attempt to synchronize notes with Ubuntu One, I get a dialog indicating that tomboy "Failed to synchronize", but doesn't list any details.  Following the suggestion on another entry, I quit tomboy and then ran "tomboy --debug" from the console. The output is below.  The error indicates a 404 is returned for the notes URLs, however I can load the URLs directly in Firefox (after logging into Ubuntu One) and receive a json response which appears normal.

I'm logged into Ubuntu One according to System > Preferences > Ubuntu One.

Not sure where to go from here...

```
    [DEBUG 10:43:26.763] SyncThread using SyncServiceAddin: Tomboy Web
[DEBUG 10:43:26.764] Building web request for URL: https://one.ubuntu.com/notes//api/1.0/
[DEBUG 10:43:27.577] Building web request for URL: https://one.ubuntu.com/notes/api/1.0/user/
[ERROR 10:43:27.806] Caught exception. Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) NOT FOUND.
[ERROR 10:43:27.806] Stack trace for previous exception:   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR 10:43:27.807] Rest of stack trace for above exception:    at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.MakeWebRequest(RequestMethod method, System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 parameters, System.String postData)
   at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.WebRequest(RequestMethod method, System.String url, System.String postData)
   at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.Get(System.String uri, IDictionary`2 queryParameters)
   at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.UserInfo.GetUser(System.String userUri, IWebConnection connection)
   at Tomboy.WebSync.WebSyncServer.BeginSyncTransaction()
   at Tomboy.Sync.SyncManager.SynchronizationThread()
[ERROR 10:43:27.807] Synchronization failed with the following exception: The remote server returned an error: (404) NOT FOUND.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

(Tomboy:14075): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_source_remove: assertion `tag > 0' failed
```

Comment: [Update] EmmyS's comment was helpful.  It turned out the auth tokens were out of sync. I removed the computer from Ubuntu One (using the website); then cleared the sync info in tomboy using the clear button on Preferences > Synchronization.  Then I went through the process of re-associating the computer with Ubuntu One, and sync is now working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/575937) on launchpad for this error with a number of different fixes that have worked for some and not worked for others.